# Can I create a MediaFile from a path in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

In my PhoneGap application I'm allowing users to upload videos from their device using the Camera.getPicture() method, which works perfectly. I want to be able to reject a video for upload if its longer than 30s.

I can do this when capturing a video using capture.captureVideo because the success function receives a mediaFile as an input parameter.

Is there some way create a mediaFile instance from a path?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Here is some sample code. You'll have to determine the file name from the full path and probably set the mime type properly.

```
var medFile = new MediaFile("VID_20121108_134716.mp4",
                            "file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20121108_134716.mp4",
                            "video/mp4");
medFile.getFormatData(function(metadata) {
    console.log("width = " + metadata.width);
    console.log("height = " + metadata.height);
    console.log("duration = " + metadata.duration);
}, function() {
    console.log("fail");
});
```

I just checked in a fix for 2.3.0 so that the mimeType is not required.

Comment: Even though I get into the success function for getFormatData(), but all of the properties of metadata are 0 :s

Comment: tried calling video.duration which works but only when I call video.load(). The problem with calling video.load() is that it opens the video in quicktime on the iPhone. Why does this HTML5 video api seem half-assed?

Comment: I only tested this on Android. So YMMV on iOS. Don't even get me started on video.